# Show that $|f|$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Show that $|f|$ is continuous, provided that $f$ is continuous.

Proof: using the definition

for all $\epsilon >0$ there exist a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x, y \in E$ and $|x-y| < \delta$ then $||f(x)|-|f(y)|| < \epsilon$

$$|f(x)| < \epsilon/2$$, and $$|f(y)| < \epsilon/2$$ then 
$$||f(x)|-|f(y)|| \leq |f(x)| + |f(y)| \leq \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2 = \epsilon $$. I am not totaly confident so far with my delta epsilon is that correct so far or do i need more clarity

Comment: Here's a thought.. do you know that the composition of continuous functions is again continuous?

Comment: yes actually i think i prove that in part b of this homework problem, why do i need to use function decomposition

Comment: Ahh bummer! The reason is that you could view $|f(x)|$ as the function $h(x) = g(f(x))$ where $g(x) = |x|$. Both $f$ and $g$ are continuous, so $h$ is continuous.

Comment: so does that mean this proof is not valid, i have to do it in terms of function decomposition

Comment: Not at all, though there is a fundamental mistake (you *cannot* say that $|f(x)| < \varepsilon/2$). My way was just an easy way to avoid the headache.

Comment: yeah i know i am just really new at this type of proof, my strongest point in math is algebra i am confident in that. but the real not so much

Answer (score 2):

Note that $||x|-|y|| \le |x-y|$. Hence
$||f(x)|-|f(y)|| \le |f(x)-f(y)|$. It follows that if 
$f$ is continuous, then so is $|f|$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint. By continuity, you know that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ and $x$ there is a $\delta$ such that if $|x-y| < \delta$, then $|f(x)-f(y)| < \varepsilon$. Now use the reverse triangle inequality.